# simple_form, manually place the field and the error label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

In a simple_form (with bootstrap integration), i have a checkbox with a short text.
The text is 'I've red'. 
In the case the user doesn't check the checkbox, the validation error is: 
'You have to confirm that you've read'. 
As you can see the look isn't very good, since i would like at least the checkbox to be alligned with the 'I've read' label and not with the error message.

[image]

This is the code:

```
<%= f.input :number_of_items, :label => "I've read" %>
```

So i tried the inline label, that is:

```
<%= f.input :number_of_items, :label => false, :inline_label => "I've read" %>
```

but now the result is as follows.

[image]

That is: the checkbox is inline with the text, and this is correct... but as you can see the error is rendered at the turn of the lines!!!

I'm looking for a solution to this specific issue.

Then I'm looking for a further customization possibility that is  a way to render independently a control and its error message.
This would help me achieve a better, ad-hoc rendering where none of the defaults fits well.

Comment: Inspect elements in firebug. I think in first option you have `i've read` as a block element and your `error and checkbox` are inline-block. Similarly in second case all three are inline-block and hence in a line. Make your error message a **block element** and it'll show up in next line